# How filter multiple column with the same condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to manipulate a DataFrame with 8 columns and 263.000 rows.

This is how to look my DF:

```
ID1          ID2         dN          dS          t           Label_ID1   Label_ID2   Group
QJY77946     NP_073551   0.0241      0.1402      0.1479      229E-CoV    229E-CoV    Intra
QJY77954     NP_073551   0.0119      0.0912      0.0870      229E-CoV    229E-CoV    Intra
QJY77954     QJY77946    0.0119      0.0439      0.0566      229E-CoV    229E-CoV    Intra
QJY77962     NP_073551   0.0119      0.0912      0.0870      229E-CoV    229E-CoV    Intra
QJY77962     QJY77946    0.0119      0.0439      0.0566      229E-CoV    229E-CoV    Intra
```

My goal is filter all the values <= 6 in the columns "dN", "dS" and "t". To make this I filter the rows when the values in any columns select (dN, dS and t) have a value <= 6.

```
df_1_S = pd.read_csv("S_YN00.csv",sep="\t", names=['ID1',"ID2","dN","dS","t","Label_ID1","Label_ID2","Group"])

S_greather_than = (df_1_S["dN"] < 6)

df_1_S.loc[S_greather_than]
```

This it works, but when I trying add more columns (dS and t):

```
S_greather_than = (df_1_S["dN"] < 6) & (df_1_S["dS"] < 6) & (df_1_S["t"] < 6)

df_1_S.loc[S_greather_than] 

different method: using or ( | ) 

S_greather_than = ((df_1_S["dN"] < 6) | (df_1_S["dS"] < 5) | (df_1_S["t"] < 6))

df_1_S.loc[S_greather_than]
```

Happens this error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I understand the problem but I don´t know how filter the rows with values <= 6 at the same time.

Any idea or help is welcome.

Thank!

Comment: Could you post the output of `df_1_S.dtypes`?

Comment: ID1 object; ID2 object; dN float64; dS object; t float64; Label_ID1 object; Label_ID2 object; Group object; dtype: object;  What do you think about that?

Comment: I see. The error is probably because 'dS' is an object. I have posted a solution, let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change data type of column 'dS' to float as follows:

`df_1_S['dS'] = df_1_S['dS'].astype(float)`

The error you are getting is probably because 'dS' column is of type 'object' as mentioned in the comments.

Your code should work fine with this change.